# How to reassign new data to a bootstrap datatable with custom columns

Tags: angularjs, datatable, bootstrap-4

First we bind an array to a bootstrap 4 datatable using ng-repeat in angularjs and it is working normally, we need to create custom filter to this binded array after initializing the datatable ex: `ng-repeat="item in arryItems | filter: { 'name': $scope.nameFilter }"` the array will list items filter but the datatable will not be updated(number of pages, number of items in page, total numbers of items,...)

`ng-repeat="center in vm.searchCentersDetails | filter: { awareness_services: $scope.awareness_services }"`

any idea how to update this datatable after changing the array.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you're asking, maybe it's my fault, but would you mind double checking your post and make it more clear if it needs it? 
Thanks.

Comment: Usually pagination means that only one page is returned from the database at a time. Is this the case for your solution? If it is Angular will only filter the single page of data that was returned from the database and is probably not showing you the correct results as there might be other data that was not returned that fits your criteria.

Comment: We have a bootstrap data table that is initialised first with the returned array, after this we added a custom filters to this table, filtering is working normally with the expected result, but the number of pages for this table is not changing and it is showing all the filtered data while we are adding a limit of 10 items to show in each page.